# layout in other devices

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi i have aproblem whit layout.
When i start the app whit android studio the layout is perfect.
If i install the app in other device is all misaligned (button,tex,ecc).

can you help me?

There is a way to make universal layouts?

This is an example of layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Profilo"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUserEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="121dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="121dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnElenco"
        android:layout_width="219dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="93dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="93dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="467dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_button1"
        android:text="ELENCO SEGNALAZIONI"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="148dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="148dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
        android:text="ADMIN"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your views have length and margins in dp- this is bad practice. You have to scale them for each density.
This's [guideline](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes) how to avoid this

Comment: ok thank you, do I have to delete everything or can I change the code?

Comment: @NicolòVolpe you can put dp value in a separate `dimen` variable and scale your dp for each screen density . For mdpi, hdpi,xhdpi etc

Comment: Ok tomorrow i try.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to make universal layouts. You should follow guidelines and set the size with respect to the screen (parent). Different screens have different aspect ratios and giving absolute values can affect your layout output.

You can start with making layouts with LinearLayout and RelativeLayout and then checkout ConstraintLayout.

Here is a small fix to your code. It should work better. All the best.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Profilo"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUserEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnElenco"
        android:layout_width="219dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background_button1"
        android:text="ELENCO SEGNALAZIONI"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvUserEmail"
        android:text="ADMIN"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```